# Excel VBA - User Defined Function - converting array related formula (CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER on a normal formula) to a UDF

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have been passing by several threads that are quite similar to my problem. However, there are various interpretations which may not be applicable to my case. I have this "regular" excel formula:

```
={IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($O$2:$O$2000,A2))), INDEX($P$2:$P$2000, MATCH(TRUE, ISNUMBER(SEARCH($O$2:$O$2000, A2)),0)), "")}
```

I wanted to convert this to Excel VBA function with the following parameters

```
FUNCTION ADVLOOKUP(TAG, SENTENCESTOLOOKAT, WORDSTOLOOKUP)
```

TAG = represents Column P on the ORIGINAL FORMULA which will be put beside each cell/row representing the SENTENCESTOLOOKAT

SENTENCESTOLOOKAT = represents A2 or any cell on column A to be targeted by the formula. This is a sentence which contains any 1 of the WORDSTOLOOKUP

WORDSTOLOOKUP = represents Column O which is the inventory of words to be searched checked on each of the SENTENCESTOLOOKAT

Sorry, I'm unable to post the Excel file because apparently I have low reputation/rep points. :( But I do appreciate if you can advice whether the said Excel formula can be converted to a UDF.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want the UDF to behave like a regular function, or like an array function ?  Should it return a single value, or multiple values?

Comment: Hi Tim, I hope that it could behave like a regular function (like a lookup function). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To only return one value, you could use a simple call to Evaluate:

```
Function ADVLOOKUP(TAG As Range, SENTENCESTOLOOKAT As Range, WORDSTOLOOKUP As Range)
    ADVLOOKUP = SENTENCESTOLOOKAT.Worksheet.Evaluate("INDEX(INDEX(" & TAG.Address & ",MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" & _
                    WORDSTOLOOKUP.Address & "," & SENTENCESTOLOOKAT.Address & ")),0)),)")
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Rory, sorry for the late response, Let me get back to to try this one out. Thank you!

Comment: I was able to check it, it works perfectly fine as the one I intended and the original equivalent formula. Thank you very much again!